# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Objec

Tags: node.js

I want to convert the data taken from the internet on a node js to json file and convert it to txt, but I get an error

```
const interactionCreate = require("../events/interactionCreate");
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const parser = new Parser()
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')
const { request } = require('undici')
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs")
const jsonToTxt = require("json-to-txt");

module.exports = {
    
    name: "adsoyad",
    description: "ad soyad bilgi ",
    options:[
        {
            name: "adı",
            description: "sorgulanacak kişi ismi",
            type: 3,
            required: true,     
                    
        },
        {
            name: "soyadı",
            description : "sorgulanacak kişi soyadı",
            type: 3,
            required: true,
        }

    ],
    run: async (client, interaction) =>{

      
        //const ad = interaction.options.getString("ad");
        
        
        // const soyad = interaction.options.getString("soyad");
        
        //const feed = await parser.parseURL(`[URL]http://141.11.127.168/ucretsizapi/adsoyad.php?ad=&soyad=sezer&auth=propenthia[/URL]`)
    
        const ad = interaction.options.getString('adı');
        const soyad = interaction.options.getString('soyadı');

        const query = new URLSearchParams({  ad });
        const query2 = new URLSearchParams({ soyad });
        
        const dictResult = await request(`http://141.11.127.168/ucretsizapi/adsoyad.php?${query}&${query2}&auth=propenthia`);
        //const list  = await dictResult.body.text();
     
        const asa = await dictResult.body.json();


        const dataInString = jsonToTxt({ filePath: asa });

        await interaction.reply("sonuclar")



        //const ms = await JSON.stringify(list)
       
        //var mars = JSON.parse(ms)
          



        
    }
}
```

When I enter the command in Discord, I want it to be sent as txt.
the error i got;
The error I get when I try to translate

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object
    at Object.open (node:fs:561:10)
    at Object.writeFile (node:fs:2185:6)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\commands\adsoyad.js:53:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:592:10)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:468:35)
    at getData (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\json-to-txt\src\lib.js:63:26)
    at main (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\json-to-txt\json_to_txt.js:5:16)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\commands\adsoyad.js:53:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I want to solve my problem fast
Thank you in advance to those who are interested.
I actually want to take json and convert it to txt. I want to specify the txty I translated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like the argument passed to jsonToTxt is an object, but it is expected to be a file path string or a buffer. To solve the issue, you need to provide a valid file path string to jsonToTxt instead of the JSON data itself.

U need the JSON data to write data to a file, then converts it to a text file:

```
const interactionCreate = require("../events/interactionCreate");
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const parser = new Parser()
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')
const { request } = require('undici')
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs")
const jsonToTxt = require("json-to-txt");

module.exports = {
    
    name: "adsoyad",
    description: "ad soyad bilgi ",
    options:[
        {
            name: "adı",
            description: "sorgulanacak kişi ismi",
            type: 3,
            required: true,     
                    
        },
        {
            name: "soyadı",
            description : "sorgulanacak kişi soyadı",
            type: 3,
            required: true,
        }

    ],
    run: async (client, interaction) =>{

      
        //const ad = interaction.options.getString("ad");
        
        
        // const soyad = interaction.options.getString("soyad");
        
        //const feed = await parser.parseURL(`[URL]http://141.11.127.168/ucretsizapi/adsoyad.php?ad=&soyad=sezer&auth=propenthia[/URL]`)
    
        const ad = interaction.options.getString('adı');
        const soyad = interaction.options.getString('soyadı');

        const query = new URLSearchParams({  ad });
        const query2 = new URLSearchParams({ soyad });
        
        const dictResult = await request(`http://141.11.127.168/ucretsizapi/adsoyad.php?${query}&${query2}&auth=propenthia`);
        //const list  = await dictResult.body.text();
     
        const asa = await dictResult.body.json();

        // Write the JSON data to a file
        fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(asa));

        // Convert the JSON data to a text file
        jsonToTxt("data.json", "data.txt");

        await interaction.reply("sonuclar")
    }
}
```

Comment: I encountered an error again

Comment: bro dude, I'm going to get the json file as txt output, so look, the txt file will be like this example: {
  "success": false,
  "message": "Not Found"
}